# Can a python @classmethod be inherited?

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method

For example, I have a base class and a derived class:

```
>>> class Base:
...   @classmethod
...   def myClassMethod(klass):
...     pass
...
>>> class Derived:
...   pass
...
>>> Base.myClassMethod()
>>> Derived.myClassMethod()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class Derived has no attribute 'myClassMethod'
```

Is it possible to have the Derived class be able to call myClassMethod without overwriting it and calling super's class method? I'd like to overwrite the class method only when it's necessary.

Comment: Your `Derived` class isn't derived from `Base`. Otherwise this would work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, they can be inherited.

If you want to inherit members, you need to tell python about the inheritance!

```
>>> class Derived(Base):
...    pass
```

In Python 2 it's a good practice to make your `Base` class inherit from object (but it will work without you doing so). In Python 3 it's unnecessary, since it already inherits from object by default (unless you're trying to make your code backwards compatible):

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     ...
```

Comment: This is only good practice in python 2.x - in 3.x it is superfluous as everything inherits from `object`.

Comment: @James: true, but most questions on SO are still about 2.7

Comment: What if after several years it ceased to be so?

Comment: @Daerdemandt then we edit the answer to say "For Python 2.x it's good practice to . . . " and call it a day

Answer (score 7):

You must derive from the base class in subclass:

```
class Derived(Base):
    ...
```